# Exposing swagger Spring Boot management port.(or any other static content )

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, static-content

We where trying to expose some static content on Spring Boot management port.

In our case it is Swagger UI.

By default Spring Boot take this static content and expose it on the business port .

We would like the Swagger to be exposed on the managment port as define by the property :

```
management.port
```

Answer (score 0):

First we declared MvcEndpoint (based on JolokiaMvcEndpoint).
We made some trick in the RequestMapping

```
 @RequestMapping("/**")

  public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        ResourceHttpRequestHandler hdlr = context.getBean(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.class);
        String reqPath = (String)request.getAttribute(PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
        request.setAttribute(PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE, reqPath.substring(path.length()));
        hdlr.handleRequest(request, response);
        return null;
    }
```

Then we needed to enable cros origin you can take a look on simple example at 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

notice that you may need to extend the example allow headers

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

We don't feel this solution is clean , but this is how we solve it if someone has more clean solution please post.